# Print keywords as part of Natbib bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I would like to print a reference sheet (for myself) of all of the references in a .bib file, that includes in the printout the keyword that codes each item.

For instance, on the item

```
@article{GrossZagier1985,
journal = {J. Reine Angew. Math.},
number = {},
pages = {191-220},
title = {On singular moduli},
author = {Gross, B. H. and Zagier, D. B.},
volume = {355},
year = {1985},}
```

I would like something along the lines of

```
[GZ85] B. H. Gross and D. B. Zagier. On singular moduli. <i> J. Reine Angew. Math.</i>, 355:191-220, 1985. <b> GrossZagier1985 </b>
```

to be printed.

I am using Natbib with the "alpha" bibliography style, but would be fine switching the package or style to another.

If it is relevant, the document is a "report" with the "letter" option.